# How to make a flow chart in beamer

Tags: flow-charts

[image][image]

Please help me to draw this image in latex beamer. I am new for this task.

Comment: What you try? This fairly simple image ....

Comment: After 117 questions one would expect to find at least an attempt to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Flowchart}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 6mm,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
     M/.style = {draw, outer sep = 1mm},
     N/.style = {M, rounded corners=3mm},
                    ]
\node (n1) [N] {text};
\node (n2) [M, right=of n1] {text};
\node (n3) [N, above right=of n2] {text};
\node (n4) [N, below right=of n2] {text};
%
\draw[arr] (n1) -- (n2);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n3);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. How can we draw four nodes, instead of two.

Comment: @Math-Man, oh, just add it in the tikzpicture. . For example `\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 6mm,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
     M/.style = {draw, outer sep = 1mm},
     N/.style = {M, rounded corners=3mm},
                    ]
\node (n1) [N] {text};
\node (n2) [M, right=of n1] {text};
\node (n3) [M, right=of n2] {text};
\node (n4) [N, above right=of n3] {text};
\node (n5) [N, below right=of n3] {text};
%
\draw[arr] (n1) -- (n2);
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n3);
\draw[arr] (n3) -- (n4);
\draw[arr] (n3) -- (n5);
    \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: You misunderstand me, Actually I am looking for four nodes vertically after second node.

Comment: @Math-Man, sorry, your question as well comment are unclear.  At list you should provi+e a sketch what you after and show us, what you try so far,

Comment: This is what i tried so far. I want to make it attractive. Sketch is added in question